# Problem - after click "show more" button, new loaded images overides section below

Tags: html, button, containers

website: https://oskars99.github.io/Page-Adrespect/

code: https://github.com/OskarS99/Page-Adrespect/blob/main/index.html
this section start from line 249.

I have a problem with the fact that after clicking the button, the container that stores the photos does not expand, only new photos appear in the next section

I would like the new photos that load to appear smoothly and the container with the photos to expand

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your title should be a clear, specific question and your post needs code (not links to code).